# python text file variable search

Tags: python

I have a text file which look like this

```
Apples: 01, Oranges: 33, Grapes: 07, Plums: 15
```

What im trying to do is have a function which checks if the desired string is in the text file and then pull the correct amount next to it. So far i have

```
def get_numbers(fruit)
  if fruit in open('example.txt'):
    #this is where im stuck on getting the correct value
    # if grapes were passed, how will i obtain 07?
  else:
    print 'some type of error'
```

Comment: Google the word *"parsing"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you construct a dictionary mapping fruit-names to the amount and then go from there.

```
>>> with open('example.txt') as f:
...     result = {k:int(v) for k,v in re.findall('([^:\s]+):\s*(\d+)', f.read())}
... 
>>> result
{'Grapes': 7, 'Plums': 15, 'Apples': 1, 'Oranges': 33}
>>> 'Grapes' in result
True
>>> 'Bananas' in result
False
>>> result['Grapes']
7
```

example.txt has the content

> Apples: 01, Oranges: 33, Grapes: 07, Plums: 15

Comment: This converts into a dictionary but when i call result['grapes'] i get

    grapes "new line"

   7

Comment: Never mind i had a print statement in my code that i did not remove.